# Adding output to ArcPy script in ArcGIS ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, modelbuilder

In ArcGIS 10.5, I have the following script which grabs the files from a geodatabase and merges them into one layer:

```
import arcpy


# specify the path to the GDB with the asset files
#make sure the path uses '/' and NOT '\'
arcpy.env.workspace = 'path/example.gdb'
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True


# collects all the Feature Classes in the GDB
fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

# run the Merge tool
arcpy.Merge_management (inputs=fcs, output='merge_result')
```

I added the script to my toolbox as 'Merge'. I then go on to add the script to my model, where I need to use the 'merge_result' output for other processes. However, when I add the script to the model, there is not 'output nodule' which I can connect to the other processes (such as Intersect, seen below). How would I go about adding an output nodule to this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To specify the output you'll want to use either [`arcpy.SetParameter()`](https://pro.arcgis.com/es/pro-app/arcpy/functions/setparameter.htm) or [`arcpy.SetParameterAsText()`](https://pro.arcgis.com/es/pro-app/arcpy/functions/setparameterastext.htm) depending if you want to output an object or return text.

I am guessing you want to use the filename of your merged feature class so I would add the following line to the end of your script:

`arcpy.SetParameterAsText(1, 'merge_result')`

Also, check this answer: [Adding output parameter to Python script tool?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/165176/adding-output-parameter-to-python-script-tool)